# The popular (c++) "error: no matching function for call to ... ", with a kick though

Tags: c++, class, initializer-list

I am working in c++.

my class `animation.h` is the following:

```
class Animation
{
public:
    Animation(ofVec2f _startLoc, ofVec2f _endLoc, float _speed, float _accel);
    virtual ~Animation();
};
```

then in `sceneMusic.h` I have another class that calls `animation` class.

```
#include "animation.h"
class sceneMusic
{
    public:
        sceneMusic();
        virtual ~sceneMusic();
    private:
        Animation staveMotion;
};
```

and `sceneMusic.cpp`

```
sceneMusic::sceneMusic()
{
    staveImg.loadImage("./sceneMusic/stave_white.png");

    staveMotion = Animation(ofVec2f(29, -staveImg.height()), \
                            ofVec2f(29, 249), 1, 0.1);
}
```

The above gives the following (expected) error:

```
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|3|error: no matching function for call to ‘Animation::Animation()’|
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|5|note: candidates are:|
src/Animation.h|14|note: Animation::Animation(ofVec2f, ofVec2f, float, float)|
src/Animation.h|14|note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided|
```

I read alot of threads that suggest I should use `initializer lists` and do in `sceneMusic.cpp`

```
sceneMusic::sceneMusic()
    :Animation(ofVec2f(29, -staveImg.height()), \
               ofVec2f(29, 249), 1, 0.1)
{
    staveImg.loadImage("./sceneMusic/stave_white.png");
}
```

or something similar.
The problem is that the `height` of staveImg will only become available once the constructor will be executed.

Also the class `sceneMusic` does not inherit class `animation`, therefore I am not sure how the above would work. If I attempt to run the above I get

```
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|4|error: type ‘Animation’ is not a direct base of ‘sceneMusic’|
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|4|error: ‘((sceneMusic*)this)->sceneMusic::staveImg.ofImage_<unsigned char>::height’ cannot be used as a function|
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|5|error: no matching function for call to ‘Animation::Animation()’|
src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|5|note: candidates are:|
...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

thank you for your help

Comment: `sceneMusic` should hold an `Animation*` called `staveMotion`.. Then `delete` it in the destructor of `sceneMusic`.. then in the `sceneMusic` constructor, you can initialise it doing `staveMotion = new Animation...` This way you do not need to provide an `Animation default constructor`.

Comment: @AndyG no I did not - i forgot it here though :)

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I could indeed but If I can avoid it I will...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the issue with your second attempt is you'd need to do this:

```
sceneMusic::sceneMusic()
    :staveMotion(ofVec2f(29, -staveImg.height()), \
               ofVec2f(29, 249), 1, 0.1)
```

You specify the member names in the initializer lists. You specify a class name only when you are attempting to call a specific super-class constructor. `Animation` is not a super-class of `sceneMusic`.

The following "no matching function for call to Animation::Animation()" occurred for the same reason it would have occurred if you didn't have anything in your initializer list at all: the `staveMotion` member was still trying to use `Animation`s default constructor (just like the default constructor is used when you declare a variable `Animation a;`), but `Animation` does not have a default constructor.

Correcting the error in the initializer list takes care of both errors.

By the way, your second error regarding `height()`: make sure there's actually a member function named `height()`. You aren't showing the code but that error seems to indicate that you actually have a member *variable* named `height`, not a function.

However, the above *still* won't fix your issue with having to call `loadImage` first (thanks chris for reminding me about that in comments).

The easiest solution to that is to revert to your first attempt, and simply provide a default (no parameter) constructor for `Animation`. As soon as you declare a non-default constructor, the compiler no longer generates a default constructor for you, and you have to explicitly declare/define `Animation::Animation()` to provide it. That way, `staveMotion` can be constructed with some default values (and won't have to be constructed in your initializer list) and then assigned to a proper value later.

A second option, by the way, that wouldn't require creation of temporary default `Animation`s first (or perhaps more importantly, wouldn't require you to implement a default constructor that possibly breaks class invariants), would be to have `staveImg` be a member field of `sceneMusic`, give it a constructor that takes an image filename and loads the image, and declare it before `staveMotion` in the member list. You wouldn't need an `Animation` default constructor for this, and you could initialize everything in the initializer list:

```
sceneMusic :: sceneMusic () :
   staveImg("./sceneMusic/stave_white.png"),
   staveMotion(ofVec2f(29, -staveImg.height()), ofVec2f(29, 249), 1, 0.1)
{
}
```

A variation on that option is to construct the image ahead of time and pass it as a parameter to the `sceneMusic` constructor. This wouldn't require a new constructor fo `staveImg`.

A third option, which CantChooseUsernames brought up in the comments, is to make `staveMotion` a pointer. You can initialize it to `NULL` and construct a `new Animation(...)` when necessary without requiring a default constructor. If you do this, don't forget to `delete` it when you are done. An automatic pointer such as `std::unique_ptr<Animation>` or one of the other smart pointers (`boost` has some too) can make that easier on you.

Comment: "The problem is that the height of staveImg will only become available once the constructor will be executed." `loadImage` needs to be called *first*.

Comment: Can also make `staveMotion` a pointer to avoid having to provide the default constructor for `Animation`.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Another good option, just remember to `delete` it. A `std::auto_ptr<Animation>` would be useful there.

Comment: Another solution depending on the type could be a function that takes a string and returns an image with that loaded such that you can initialize the image member with it first. I'm not quite sure what or where `staveImg` is, though. @JasonC, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated, but that's the right direction. Alternatives include the C++11 smart pointers or Boost's.

Comment: @JasonC, Yes, `std::unique_ptr` is the usual replacement for `std::auto_ptr`. Another option that might convey the semantics more clearly would be something like `boost::optional`. All of these seem more like workarounds imo, though.

Comment: @JasonC Hi there, if I declare a default constructor in `animation`, and I compile my initial `sceneMusic.cpp` , I get the error : src/awards/sceneMusic.cpp|10|error:  ` ‘((sceneMusic*)this)->sceneMusic::staveImg.ofImage_<unsigned char>::height’ cannot be used as a function|  ` . what is wrong here?

Comment: @nass I commented on that in my answer: *"Make sure there's actually a member function named `height()`. You aren't showing the code but that error seems to indicate that you actually have a member variable named `height`, not a function."*

Comment: @chris Thanks! Re: workarounds; definitely. There are bigger fundamental design issues here that are outside the scope of my answer / limits of my motivation to address.

Comment: @JasonC Ah crap , I get an undefined reference to `Animation::Animation()` on the constructor of the `sceneMusic::sceneMusic()`

Comment: @nass Well you have to define it, of course, not just declare it.

Comment: indeed I had to change the default constructor in animation.h from `Animation();` to `Animation(){};`

Answer (score 2):

you need a default constructor class Animation since you provide parameter constructor ,the compiler would not generate one for you

```
Animation() {}
```

Comment: @JasonC，I see, you answer make it pretty clear about the initializing part